# Unable to install a windows app using wine

Tags: wine

I am trying to run a windows app on my Ubuntu 18.04 and I am getting an error message as follows:

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00000004 in 32-bit code (0x011a3430).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:011a3430 ESP:0033cbf0 EBP:0033cbfc EFLAGS:00210246(  R- --  I  Z- -P- )
 EAX:0033cc08 EBX:0001058c ECX:00000000 EDX:00000000
 ESI:00f1f984 EDI:0033dc48
Stack dump:
0x0033cbf0:  0000003c 0033cc08 00000000 0033cc64
0x0033cc00:  0119f322 0033cc08 0033cc28 7e7705d2
0x0033cc10:  00000001 00f1f984 0033cc70 011a384e
0x0033cc20:  0141a948 0033cc40 0033cc58 7e70fd86
0x0033cc30:  013cd178 053aca38 00f2003c 7e70fd86
0x0033cc40:  0001058c 00f1f984 053aca90 01254834
Backtrace:
=>0 0x011a3430 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in controlsdll (0x0033cbfc)
  1 0x0119f322 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in controlsdll (0x0033cc64)
  2 0x0119fca1 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in controlsdll (0x0033d658)
  3 0x0119bee4 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in controlsdll (0x0033d664)
  4 0x0121d1af EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in controlsdll (0x0033d670)
  5 0x78d9dc27 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in mfc100 (0x0033d7e8)
  6 0x7e722295 HOOKPROC_wrapper+0x534() in user32 (0x0033d898)
  7 0x7e722948 HOOKPROC_wrapper+0xbe7() in user32 (0x0033db78)
  8 0x7e774043 GetProcessDefaultLayout+0x9a2() in user32 (0x0033dd18)
  9 0x7e76db02 CreateWindowExA+0x111() in user32 (0x0033df88)
  10 0x78da3dd2 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in mfc100 (0x0033dffc)
  11 0x78d9dedf EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in mfc100 (0x0033e070)
  12 0x78d9df92 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in mfc100 (0x0033e0b0)
  13 0x78da4d03 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in mfc100 (0x0033e0d8)
  14 0x78da4d26 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in mfc100 (0x0033e0f4)
  15 0x011a05e3 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in controlsdll (0x0033e114)
  16 0x008ef79b EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in nesttrader (0x0033e1d8)
  17 0x008f001e EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in nesttrader (0x0033e270)
  18 0x008efcb1 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in nesttrader (0x0033e298)
  19 0x00931fde EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in nesttrader (0x0033e330)
  20 0x00929bee EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in nesttrader (0x0033e440)
  21 0x78d3f282 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in mfc100 (0x0033e448)
  22 0x7e77e45a WINPROC_wrapper+0x19() in user32 (0x0033e478)
  23 0x7e77ebcd EditWndProcA+0x65c() in user32 (0x0033e4c8)
  24 0x7e7813a8 CallWindowProcW+0x177() in user32 (0x0033e508)
  25 0x7e70c804 DefDlgProcA+0x73() in user32 (0x0033e558)
  26 0x7e77e45a WINPROC_wrapper+0x19() in user32 (0x0033e598)
  27 0x7e77eab9 EditWndProcA+0x548() in user32 (0x0033e5e8)
  28 0x7e7811b3 CallWindowProcA+0x82() in user32 (0x0033e648)
  29 0x78d9e2b5 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in mfc100 (0x0033e678)
  30 0x0092923d EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in nesttrader (0x0033e694)
  31 0x78d9d7ce EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in mfc100 (0x0033e778)
  32 0x78d9f312 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in mfc100 (0x0033e798)
  33 0x78d9d6ff EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in mfc100 (0x0033e810)
  34 0x78d9d98b EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in mfc100 (0x0033e834)
  35 0x78c959bd EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in mfc100 (0x0033e878)
  36 0x7e77e45a WINPROC_wrapper+0x19() in user32 (0x0033e8a8)
  37 0x7e77eab9 EditWndProcA+0x548() in user32 (0x0033e8f8)
  38 0x7e77eec6 EditWndProcA+0x955() in user32 (0x0033edb8)
  39 0x7e7810ad EditWndProcA+0x2b3c() in user32 (0x0033edf8)
  40 0x7e73ecbe TranslateAcceleratorA+0x48d() in user32 (0x0033ee68)
  41 0x7e745d2d GetGUIThreadInfo+0x413c() in user32 (0x0033eec8)
  42 0x7e745fd0 SendMessageW+0x5f() in user32 (0x0033ef18)
  43 0x7e711f4b GetNextDlgTabItem+0xf4a() in user32 (0x0033f1f8)
  44 0x7e712cba CreateDialogIndirectParamAorW+0x39() in user32 (0x0033f228)
  45 0x7e712d02 CreateDialogIndirectParamA+0x31() in user32 (0x0033f268)
  46 0x78d3f741 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in mfc100 (0x0033f2e0)
  47 0x78d3f5c6 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in mfc100 (0x0033f2fc)
  48 0x78d3f572 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in mfc100 (0x0033f318)
  49 0x78d3f529 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in mfc100 (0x0033f33c)
  50 0x00402ca8 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in nesttrader (0x0033f350)
  51 0x0066e55d EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in nesttrader (0x0033f464)
  52 0x00b9686b EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in nesttrader (0x0033f5c0)
  53 0x00bb493c EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in nesttrader (0x0033f7b0)
  54 0x025d48a3 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in nestconnection (0x0033f808)
  55 0x025d1907 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in nestconnection (0x0033f84c)
  56 0x025d198d EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in nestconnection (0x0033f894)
  57 0x025d1b08 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in nestconnection (0x0033f8e0)
  58 0x78d8ab72 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in mfc100 (0x0033fa0c)
  59 0x78d8b08d EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in mfc100 (0x0033fa2c)
  60 0x78d8b44e EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in mfc100 (0x0033fa34)
  61 0x78d9f62e EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in mfc100 (0x0033faf8)
  62 0x78d9f312 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in mfc100 (0x0033fb18)
  63 0x78d9d6ff EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in mfc100 (0x0033fb90)
  64 0x78d9d98b EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in mfc100 (0x0033fbb4)
  65 0x78c959bd EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in mfc100 (0x0033fbf8)
  66 0x7e77e45a WINPROC_wrapper+0x19() in user32 (0x0033fc28)
  67 0x7e77eab9 EditWndProcA+0x548() in user32 (0x0033fc78)
  68 0x7e780f8a EditWndProcA+0x2a19() in user32 (0x0033fcc8)
  69 0x7e740c5c DispatchMessageA+0x9b() in user32 (0x0033fdd8)
  70 0x78d8be8c EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in mfc100 (0x0033fe18)
  71 0x78db1ce4 EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in mfc100 (0x0033fe2c)
  72 0x00c0dbcf EntryPoint+0xffffffff() in nesttrader (0x0033fec0)
  73 0x7b463692 call_process_entry+0x11() in kernel32 (0x0033fed8)
  74 0x7b46590e ExitProcess+0x226d() in kernel32 (0x0033ffd8)
  75 0x7b46369e call_process_entry+0x1d() in kernel32 (0x0033ffec)
0x011a3430 EntryPoint+0xffffffff in controlsdll: movl   0x4(%ecx),%edx
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (122 modules)
PE    340000-  356000   Deferred        zlibwapi
PE    360000-  372000   Deferred        zlib1
PE    380000-  3c0000   Deferred        reportgenerator
PE    3c0000-  3d3000   Deferred        nesttools
PE    400000- 115d000   Export          nesttrader
PE   1160000- 1186000   Deferred        nestiw
PE   1190000- 128b000   Export          controlsdll
PE   25d0000- 25e4000   Export          nestconnection
PE  10000000-10261000   Deferred        connectnest
PE  78b60000-78f98000   Export          mfc100
ELF 7ac00000-7ac86000   Deferred        riched20<elf>
  \-PE  7ac10000-7ac86000   \               riched20
ELF 7b400000-7b7ee000   Dwarf           kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b420000-7b7ee000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bd00000   Deferred        ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bd00000   \               ntdll
ELF 7c000000-7c004000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7c4a3000-7c514000   Deferred        libjpeg.so.8
ELF 7c5cf000-7c600000   Deferred        netapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7c5e0000-7c600000   \               netapi32
ELF 7c726000-7c73e000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 7c75a000-7c77a000   Deferred        dnsapi<elf>
  \-PE  7c760000-7c77a000   \               dnsapi
ELF 7c99a000-7ca5e000   Deferred        windowscodecs<elf>
  \-PE  7c9b0000-7ca5e000   \               windowscodecs
ELF 7ca5e000-7cb9b000   Deferred        actxprxy<elf>
  \-PE  7ca80000-7cb9b000   \               actxprxy
ELF 7cb9b000-7cc17000   Deferred        wininet<elf>
  \-PE  7cba0000-7cc17000   \               wininet
ELF 7cdd8000-7cddf000   Deferred        libnss_dns.so.2
ELF 7cddf000-7ce08000   Deferred        propsys<elf>
  \-PE  7cdf0000-7ce08000   \               propsys
ELF 7ce08000-7ce1c000   Deferred        riched32<elf>
  \-PE  7ce10000-7ce1c000   \               riched32
ELF 7ce1c000-7ce45000   Deferred        mpr<elf>
  \-PE  7ce20000-7ce45000   \               mpr
ELF 7ce8b000-7cec3000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7ce90000-7cec3000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7cec3000-7ceca000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7ceca000-7ced6000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7ced6000-7cee9000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7cee9000-7cef6000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7cef6000-7cf02000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7cf65000-7cf69000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7cf69000-7cf70000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7cf70000-7cf74000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7cf74000-7cf7e000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF 7cf7e000-7cf99000   Deferred        libbsd.so.0
ELF 7cf99000-7cfa0000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7cfa0000-7cfa4000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7cfa4000-7cfd0000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7cfd0000-7d11a000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7d11a000-7d12f000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7d131000-7d149000   Deferred        dwmapi<elf>
  \-PE  7d140000-7d149000   \               dwmapi
ELF 7d14b000-7d1db000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7d160000-7d1db000   \               winex11
ELF 7d221000-7d253000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7d253000-7d29e000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7d29e000-7d2bd000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7d2bd000-7d2f7000   Deferred        libpng16.so.16
ELF 7d2f7000-7d3b4000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7d3d0000-7d465000   Deferred        gdiplus<elf>
  \-PE  7d3e0000-7d465000   \               gdiplus
ELF 7d465000-7d490000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  7d470000-7d490000   \               msacm32
ELF 7d490000-7d549000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  7d4a0000-7d549000   \               winmm
ELF 7d549000-7d66c000   Deferred        msvcp100<elf>
  \-PE  7d590000-7d66c000   \               msvcp100
ELF 7d66c000-7d795000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7d680000-7d795000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7d795000-7d81a000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7d7a0000-7d81a000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7d81a000-7d975000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7d830000-7d975000   \               ole32
ELF 7d975000-7d999000   Deferred        shcore<elf>
  \-PE  7d980000-7d999000   \               shcore
ELF 7d999000-7e359000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7d9b0000-7e359000   \               shell32
ELF 7e359000-7e36d000   Deferred        msimg32<elf>
  \-PE  7e360000-7e36d000   \               msimg32
ELF 7e36d000-7e391000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7e370000-7e391000   \               imm32
ELF 7e391000-7e3d7000   Deferred        usp10<elf>
  \-PE  7e3a0000-7e3d7000   \               usp10
ELF 7e3d7000-7e514000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7e3e0000-7e514000   \               comctl32
ELF 7e514000-7e583000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e520000-7e583000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7e583000-7e59d000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7e590000-7e59d000   \               version
ELF 7e59d000-7e6cc000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e5b0000-7e6cc000   \               gdi32
ELF 7e6cc000-7e8d4000   Dwarf           user32<elf>
  \-PE  7e6e0000-7e8d4000   \               user32
ELF 7e8d4000-7e9ae000   Deferred        msvcr100<elf>
  \-PE  7e8f0000-7e9ae000   \               msvcr100
ELF 7e9ae000-7e9e5000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7e9c0000-7e9e5000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7e9e5000-7e9ff000   Deferred        wsock32<elf>
  \-PE  7e9f0000-7e9ff000   \               wsock32
ELF 7e9ff000-7ea78000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7ea10000-7ea78000   \               advapi32
ELF 7ea78000-7eaa3000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  7ea80000-7eaa3000   \               iphlpapi
ELF 7eaa3000-7eb5a000   Deferred        msvcrt<elf>
  \-PE  7eac0000-7eb5a000   \               msvcrt
ELF 7eb5a000-7eb74000   Deferred        crtdll<elf>
  \-PE  7eb60000-7eb74000   \               crtdll
ELF 7eb74000-7eb88000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7eb88000-7eba3000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7eba3000-7ebb1000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7eee2000-7efe4000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efec000-7f000000   Deferred        psapi<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000   \               psapi
ELF f7b03000-f7b0d000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF f7b0f000-f7b14000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f7b14000-f7cf0000   Deferred        libc.so.6
ELF f7cf0000-f7d0f000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF f7d2b000-f7ee2000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f7ee4000-f7f0c000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    00000020    0
    0000001b    0
    00000013    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000011 winedevice.exe
    00000018    0
    00000017    0
    00000016    0
    00000012    0
00000019 plugplay.exe
    0000001d    0
    0000001c    0
    0000001a    0
0000001e winedevice.exe
    00000025    0
    00000022    0
    00000021    0
    0000001f    0
00000023 explorer.exe
    00000028    0
    00000027    0
    00000026    0
    00000024    0
00000029 (D) C:\Program Files (x86)\Omnesys\NEST3\NestTrader.exe
    00000032    0
    00000031    0
    00000030    0
    0000002f    2
    0000002e    0
    0000002d    0
    0000002c    0
    0000002b    0
    0000002a    0 <==

System information:
    Wine build: wine-4.0-rc1
    Platform: i386 (WOW64)
    Version: Windows 7
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 4.15.0-39-generic
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I'm facing the same error with the NOW Launcher.